# Использовать Font Awesome через CSS

Tags: css

Подскажите, мне надо перед текстом который находиться в li, путями css, поместить **Icons**(из font awesome). Как я понимаю надо через content, но когда  вписываю юникод, то вместо иконки, выводит сам юникод.

```
 .list li:before {

     content: 'f04b'; }
```

ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ГДЕ Я ТУПЛЮ, **БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно ещё указать сам шрифт, а перед юникодом нужно ставить слэш:

```
.list li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f04b'; 
}
```